# Why app icon in taskbar is not transparent in Windows 10?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-8.1, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I have created a Universal app for Windows 10. I use Visual Studio 2015 RTM and in Manifest > Visual Effects, I placed my icon in the 24x24 square box. It is transparent, I can see it in Photoshop and also in Visual Studio, in Visual Effects page. The background in manifest is also set to "transparent".
When I run the app, the icon appears in the Windows task bar, but it is not transparent and it used the blue color as background.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you click that the picture in the 44x44 logo for 24x24 size it says:

Note: The tile background color is shown through transparent sections of this image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iJha.png)

It's also a good idea to follow this File name format if you don't want the system to put a backplate on your icon: 
*AppList.targetsize-*_altform-unplated.PNG

Comment: Yes, this message appears.